# How can you starting and stop a meteor server remotely?

Tags: node.js, unix, build, build-automation, meteor

I'm using [meteor](http://meteor.com). You can run the meteor server with `meteor run`. Lets say I have my own server (unix) somewhere I can ssh into. I have a build script that copies the latest source from a git repo onto that server. I need that script to stop the last running meteor server, and start the new one after transferring the files. **What's a good way to start and stop the meteor server programatically?**

Comment: I've heard [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) could be useful in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor is built ontop of Node.js. you could always create a script that looks for node.js and exits it (bash script). I've never personally tried it but there is a node command called `process.exit()` within meteor.

Also keep in mind using `meteor run` is for development. Once you bundle your package up its run off of node.js

Also have alook at a project called `meteorite` (https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) which you could also get to update packages off of git as well your meteor itself

Edit: I forgot about meteor's magical ability to scan for file changes and automatically update these to the client with minimum interruption without having to restart too!

Comment: This is for an internal app (company intranet only), so I would like to use the built in mongo setup if possible, to make running, using, and actively developing the app as simple as possible, without doing additional setup on the vm (now that nodejs and meteor) have been installed.

Comment: It shouldn't really be necessary to restart meteor. If you copy and paste the updates on while its running it'll handle these changes in a hot-swap manner as the files are uploaded or even edited in real time.

Comment: Alas, the git repo contains the .meteor folder (all the source files), so the app would (and does) crash when the files are replaced while it is running.

Comment: I'm slightly confused do you want to update meteor or the source code of your app? .meteor only contains the database and meteor's internal files. You could use meteorite these to update these quite easily it automatically updates these on startup

Comment: I would just be updating the source code. The git repo includes the .meteor folder, however.

Comment: If I were to gitignore the .meteor folder, wouldn't that mean the packages used in the meteor project would have to be manually updated on the server whenever they changed?

Comment: Yes if you ignored the .meteor folder it should work as you expect it. Yes as meteor is updated you would need to stop and run `meteor update` to update its packages and itself and start it up again.

Comment: You could also run meteor update while meteor is running, and then quickly restart your app too

Comment: I don't mean updating to new versions of packages, I mean adding and removing packages. (Lets say I decided to start using bootstrap, or less).

Comment: You can update/add/remove meteor packages while meteor is running and they will automatically be pushed to the browser without a restart